# Xamarin.Forms CustomRenderer UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am creating chat application in Xamarin.Forms. I want to make rectangle which looks like 'chat bubble'. As I remember in WPF app I could add RadiusX and RadiousY properties to rectangle to achive corner radius.

However when I do it with my renderer I see no effect. When I add stroke then I see that stroke has corner radious but 'fill' is still square.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.RadiusY = 10;
            Control.RadiusX = 10;
            Control.StrokeThickness = 10;
            Control.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
            Control.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.PaleVioletRed);
        }
```

Actual effect:

[image]

Comment: I think that the inner square is rounded, but the effect is very subtle. Did you try to raise the value of Radius to check if it becomes more rounded?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot paste picture in comments but your code works for me. Do you want to show the page xaml you have control in?